# UbuntuOne: What happen if I delete my folder

Tags: ubuntu-one

I started using UbuntuOne and I must admit that I am fairly new to this file sharing concept...

So I was wondering, what would happen if my folder containing all of my files were deleted on my computer (like, with a format...).

Would I lose these files or could I recreate the folder after the format and get back my files ?

Thanks !

Comment: I will format in a close future and post my results here if someone ever need a confirmation that formatting allows to recuperate the folder with all of its files.

Comment: That will be great!

Answer (score 5):

What happens when you delete a folder that is synced to Ubuntu One is different from what happens when you format your hard drive.

If you delete a folder of a file, when Ubuntu One syncs, it notes what you you have done and does the same thing in the server. Then when you login to another device that is in sync with Ubuntu One, the same information is passed on to that device and the folder is deleted as well.

However, when you format a partition containing Ubuntu One installation and your synced data from a LiveCD or USB, the Ubuntu One client software gets erased and cannot run. Thus, the server doesn't know what has happened to your folder and won't delete it until you reinstall Ubuntu and Ubuntu One and login to your Ubuntu One account. At that point the server may treat your newly formatted computer to be a new computer and Ubuntu One will download all the synced folders and files.

Answer (score 3):

If you delete the folder while ubuntu one process is running, then yes, the data will be deleted.

But if you delete the folder from outside of UBUNTU  then the data will not be deleted. Such as from another Linux system.

This is because when you delete a folder from Ubuntu (while the process which is communicating with the server is running) a message passed from your system to the server telling it to delete the folder there. But this isn't the case while formatting. Because you can't format a running system's partition and doing that from outside  has the absence of the ubuntu one process

Answer (score 2):

you can get your folder from ubuntuone online again

Answer (score 0):

UbuntuOne is a cloud service. Changes done within the folder will affect the computers associated with your account. The way this works is that when files within your folder are deleted, added, changed locally, they are uploaded to the cloud server and then redownloaded/updated on your other computers when possible.

Further explanation and possibly off-topic, I **need confirmation on this statement**, but I'd think this is fact: Deleting files INSIDE UbuntuOne updates your cloud filesystem, deleting the entire UbuntuOne folder (in /home/accountname) will not delete the filesystem (when the OS and background service is running). Firstly when formatting, the OS and background service is not running, which means no deleting files.